# How to localize multiple Views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI, and my app also needs the feature translate language, so I have created a sample app first before incorporating this functionality to my other project. So as you can see in my code below, I can
change the language by clicking the button, and it works flawlessly, but I have no idea how this would work with multiple views. I'm looking to localize all of them and want to remove redundancies.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var title = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(title)
                .padding()
            Button {
                title = "welcomeTitle".localizableString("en")
            } label: {
                Text("EN")
            }
            Button {
                title = "welcomeTitle".localizableString("ja")
            } label: {
                Text("JA")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
//            title = "welcomeTitle".localizableString("en")
            if(Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first == "ja"){
                title = "welcomeTitle".localizableString("ja")
            }
            else{
                title = "welcomeTitle".localizableString("en")
            }
               }
              
    }
}

extension String {
    func localizableString(_ name: String) -> String {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
           
           
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to do it. You just use Localization Files and then use your keys. You shouldn't change the language manually, the user can go to the Settings App and set a different language for the application (if required and the local language should not apply)

Comment: thank you I got your idea let me try first.

Answer (score 0):

See before [this](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/swiftui-tutorial-localization)

Then a convenient extension:

```swift
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}


//For your button
Button {
 //action
} label: {
Text("welcomeTitle".localized)
}
```

In your Localizable.strings file English, add the following:
`"welcomeTitle" = "welcomeTitle EN";`

In your Localizable.strings file Japanese, add the following:
`"welcomeTitle" = "welcomeTitle JA";`

Comment: thanks for replying sir, let me try with your code first.